# Entropy Theory and Conditional Entropy

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, ergodic-theory, entropy

Peter Walters An Introduction to Ergodic Theory.

Chapter 4

Entropy

Page 83 & 84

How did they duduce the last formula ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall from properties of conditional expectation that

1. (Conditioning a.k.a. law of total expectation) For every $f\in L^1(X,\mathscr{B},m)$, we have
   \begin{align}
      \int f\,\mathrm{d}m &=
         \int \mathbb{E}[f\,|\,\mathscr{C}]\,\mathrm{d}m \;.
   \end{align}
2. (Pulling out known factors) For every $u,v:X\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $u,uv\in L^1(X,\mathscr{B},m)$ and $v$ is $\mathscr{C}$-measurable, we have
   \begin{align}
      \mathbb{E}[uv\,|\,\mathscr{C}] &=
         \mathbb{E}[u\,|\,\mathscr{C}] v
   \end{align}
   $m$-almost surely.

Now back to your case, for each $i$ we have
\begin{align}
   \int \underbrace{\chi_{A_i}\log\mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}]}_{f} \,\mathrm{d}m &=
      \int \mathbb{E}\Big[
         \underbrace{\chi_{A_i}}_{u}\smash{\overbrace{\log\mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}]}^{v}}
      \,\Big|\,\mathscr{C}
      \Big] \,\mathrm{d}m \\
   &=
      \int \mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}]
         \log\mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}]
         \,\mathrm{d}m \;,
\end{align}
from which can conclude the equality on the 3rd line of page 84.

To see the equality on the 2nd line of page 84, note that for each $j$ and $m$-almost every $x\in C_j$, the function $\mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}](x)$ has the constant value $m(A_i\,|\,C_j)$.  This is intuitively clear, but can formally be seen by verifying that the function
\begin{align}
   g(x) &:= \sum_{j}\chi_{C_j}(x)m(A_i\,|\,C_j)
\end{align}
is a version of the conditional expectation $\mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}]$ (i.e., it satisfies the definition).
Thus,
\begin{align}
   -\sum_{j=1}^k\int\chi_{A_i}\log\mathbb{E}[\chi_{A_i}\,|\,\mathscr{C}]\,\mathrm{d}m &=
      -\sum_{i=1}^k\int \sum_{j=1}^p\chi_{A_i}\chi_{C_j}\log m(A_i\,|\,C_j) \,\mathrm{d}m \\
   &=
      -\sum_{i,j}\Big(\log m(A_i\,|\,C_j)\Big)\int\chi_{A_i\cap C_j}\,\mathrm{d}m \\
   &=
      -\sum_{i,j}m(A_i\cap C_j)\log m(A_i\,|\,C_j) \;.
\end{align}

Comment: How did they move from the first line in page 84 to the second ones ?

Comment: Oh, I thought you had problem only with the last line.  Let me update my answer ...